# Unity 2D, how to turn a bool true, after a set amount of time?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I have an enemy working to damage the player when they stay in collision for too long, at the moment, the enemy will attack about 30 times per second, however I want there to be a delay between each enemy attack, here is my current code:

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col){

    if (col.collider.CompareTag ("Player") && canAttack == true) {
        player.Damage (enemyDamage);
        canAttack = false;
        //wait 3 seconds or so 
        canAttack = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerator OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
{

    if (col.collider.CompareTag ("Player") && canAttack == true) 
    {
        player.Damage (enemyDamage);
        canAttack = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); 
        canAttack = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: wait you can to coroutine yields in the middle of a non-IEnumerable method?!?

Comment: Please use words to describe your solution before providing the code.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the `Invoke` command.

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col){

    if (col.collider.CompareTag ("Player") && canAttack == true) {
        player.Damage (enemyDamage);
        canAttack = false;
        //wait 3 seconds or so 
        Invoke("EnableAttack", 3f); // Invoke will call a given function after the time given in seconds.
    }
}

void EnableAttack() {
    canAttack = true;
}
```

Comment: I would advice not to use invoke, because it can be easily broken when refactoring (naming of method).

Comment: @M156 How would you implement this? I don't know of any reasonable way to wait for s seconds without using the method's name.

Comment: For example see C0DEX answer. But generally you can use StartCoroutine. Yes it is more code, due to boilerplate, but it is more resistant to refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution to using the coroutine system is to store the time when the object attacked last in a private variable and compare it to the current time:

```
public class Attacker : MonoBehaviour {

    private float lastAttackTime;
    private const float ATTACK_DELAY = 0.1f; // 10 attacks per second

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col){

    if (col.collider.CompareTag ("Player")) {
        if (Time.time > lastAttackTime + ATTACK_DELAY) {
             player.Damage (enemyDamage);
             // ... and other attack stuff
             lastAttackTime = Time.time;
        }
    }
}
```